# Mailchimp List Member Post Issue

Tags: c#, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am testing Mailchimp API 3.0 to add some members to a specific list.

The post request to add new members works great. But if I go to MailChimp website and manually delete the new member from the list and then try to add the same member again, I receive an bad request error, informing the member already exists on the list.

Why is this happening, if the list member is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

When mailchimp deletes a member, it only marks it as deleted. It still exists and when you upload it again, you violate a unique key index. You can have duplicates as long as their IDs are different.